# how my event listener works inside an event listener?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
const range = document.querySelector('.range');
const color = document.getElementById("color");
const pallet = document.querySelector('.pallet');
const input = document.querySelector('.input');
const number = document.createElement('span');
const rowdivs = document.createElement('div');
    
input.append(number)

range.addEventListener('input', e=>{
  number.textContent = range.value
  pallet.textContent = '' 

  for(let i = 0 ; i < number.textContent -1 ; ++i) {
    const rowdivs = document.createElement('div')
    rowdivs.setAttribute('class' , 'rowdivs') 
    pallet.append(rowdivs)
  }
  
  let rowdiv = document.querySelectorAll('.rowdivs');

  rowdiv.forEach(e => {
    for(let i = 0 ; i < number.textContent +1 ; ++i){ 
      const columndiv = document.createElement('div')
      columndiv.setAttribute('class', 'columndiv');
      e.append(columndiv)
      columndiv.addEventListener('mouseover', e=>{
        columndiv.style.backgroundColor = color.value
      })
    }
  })
})
```

I don't know why

```
columndiv.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    columndiv.style.backgroundColor = color.value
}
```

this event listener is working inside an range event listener.
Shouldn't it work only while I'm holding the range input because it's inside the range event listener? I know my question sounds dumb but please help me.

I tried to call to add an event listener out side of it but it didn't work. I was expecting it to work.

Comment: I can't exactly tell what this code does, but it seems like you are creating elements and adding a `mouseover` (hover) event to these new elements every time in `input` event happens.

Comment: Note that you’re attaching more and more mouseover event listeners with every input event. That’s probably not what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

This is might because event listeners remain attached to the elements they were added to, until they are explicitly removed. Once attached, the **columndiv** event listener will respond to **mouseover** events on the dynamically created **columndiv** elements, regardless of the **range** input's state.